# How to get the X & Y position of an iframe from within the Iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have an iframe on a document. Using javascript, I can get the iframe's width and height and the document's width and height. I now need to get the x,y position of the iframe on the document from within the iframe.

Code is something like:

```
<html>
<iframe>
var documentWidth = parent.window.innerWidth;
var documentHeight = parent.window.innerHeight;
var iframeWidth = window.innerWidth;
var iframeHeight = window.innerHeight;
var iframeX = ????
</iframe>
<html>
```

I've tried window.offsetTop/Left, parent.window.offsetTop/Left, window.clientTop, etc and anything else I can find but keep getting 'undefined'.

Both are on the same server so I don't think I have a cross domain issue.

Any ideas?

BTW I can't use JQuery for this. JS Only.

Here is a bit more detail:

```
<html>
<body>
<div>
<iframe name="iframe/123/Test">
<html>
<body>
<script src="same domain"></script>
</body>
</html>
</iframe>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The script looks like this so far:

```
// JavaScript Document
var documentWidth = parent.window.innerWidth;
var documentHeight = parent.window.innerHeight;
var iframeWidth = window.innerWidth;
var iframeHeight = window.innerHeight;
var iframeName = window.name;
var iframeX = window.parent.document.getElementsByName(iframeName).offsetLeft;

//Var Dumps
document.write("Document Width: "+documentWidth+"<br>");
document.write("Document Height: "+documentHeight+"<br>");
document.write("Iframe Width: "+iframeWidth+"<br>");
document.write("Iframe Height: "+iframeHeight+"<br>");
document.write("Iframe X: "+iframeX+"<br>");
```

I get the following results on page in the iframe:

```
Document Width: 1566
Document Height: 652
Iframe Width: 300
Iframe Height: 250
Iframe X: undefined
```

Comment: I posted working code here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53056796/getboundingclientrect-from-within-iframe/53872705#53872705

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since both files are on same server, so you dont have cross domain issue, You can try following solution:

Main Html

```
<html>
 <body>
   <iframe src='iframe.html' name='iframe_name' id='iframe_id'></iframe>
 </body>
</html>
```

Iframe Code [iframe.html]:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       var documentWidth = parent.window.innerWidth;
       var documentHeight = parent.window.innerHeight;
       var iframeWidth = window.innerWidth;
       var iframeHeight = window.innerHeight;
       // Get Left Position
       var iframeX = window.parent.document.getElementById('iframe_id').offsetLeft;
       // Get Top Position
       var iframeY = window.parent.document.getElementById('iframe_id').offsetTop;
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried window.parent.document.getElementsByName(iframeName).offsetLeft; and it returns undefinied unfortunately.

I am getting the name with var iframeName = window.name;

I don't think that is the issue though because I even tried hard typing it in.

Comment: in that case you can use window.parent.document.getElementsByName(iframeName)[0].offsetTop and window.parent.document.getElementsByName(iframeName)[0].offsetLeft

Comment: Thanks for the continuing help. I changed the last line in the JS before the var dumps to "var iframeX = window.parent.document.getElementsByName(iframeName)[0].offsetLeft;" 

Now none of the var dumps show up so I assume the code must be breaking because of the [0]. 

Any thought on what could be breaking the code?

Comment: Nevermind, this works!! I tried a different browser. The iframe must have been caching. Thank you so much!!

Comment: Please be aware that `window.parent` is accessible only for iframes with same domain.

Answer (score 5):

`window.parent.document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')` will reference every iframe in the parent's window.  From there you can find your specific iframe by looping through and checking the `src` attribute.

Once you have your iframe, you can get it's dimensions and locations with the properties from [`element.getBoundingRect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.getBoundingClientRect).

```
var iframes = window.parent.document.getElementsByTagName('iframe');

var yourURL = 'test.com';
var iframe;

for (var i = 0; i < iframes.length; i++) {
    if (iframes[i].src == 'test.com') {
        iframe = iframes[i];
        break;
    }
}

var rect = iframe.getBoundingClientRect();
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I know the name of the iframe .. or how to get it atleast .. so I am doing this:
var iframeName = window.name;
var iframeX = window.parent.document.getElementsByName(iframeName).getBoundingClientRect();

However, whenever I add "getBoundingClientRect();" my script breaks. Any thoughts?

Comment: getBoundingClientRect() only works on a single element.
getElementsByName(iframeName) returns an array of elements.
getElementsByName(iframeName)[0].getBoundingClientRect() should work.

Comment: I'm working with a Chromium-based browser and frame objects do NOT have a getBoundingClientRect() method.