# How to get the coordinate of an element based on current window in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom

With Javascript in DOM, I can use [getBoundingClientRect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) to get the coordinate of the element, but it is based on **viewport**. The height of address bar and title bar are not included as I want to get the coordinate based on current browser window.

Is there a reliable method for get coordinate of element based on current browser window?

I tried use `window.outerHeight - (window.innerHeight * window.devicePixelRatio)` as the height of address bar and title bar, but it seems unreliable like it will be incorrect if the download bar is showing up in the bottom of the browser window.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the page offset on a mouse event and then get your browser window offset. Doesn't work inside an iframe, we need access a iframe from the parent window, some solutions here: [getBoundingClientRect from within iFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53056796/getboundingclientrect-from-within-iframe)

[image]

```
const pageOffset = {};
// you can collect the page offset on mouse move too
document.addEventListener('mousemove', async e => {
    pageOffset.x = e.screenX - e.pageX;
    pageOffset.y = e.screenY - e.pageY;
});

const $button = document.querySelector('button');

$button.addEventListener('click', e => {

    pageOffset.x = e.screenX - e.pageX;
    pageOffset.y = e.screenY - e.pageY;

    const rect = $button.getBoundingClientRect();
    alert(['x:', pageOffset.x - window.screenLeft + rect.left, 'y:', pageOffset.y - window.screenTop + rect.top].join(' '));
});
```